# CORS withCredentials XHR preflight not posting Cookies in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, cookies, cross-domain

I'm trying to do a CORS XHR post w/ credentials.  It works great in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  The cookies are not present in the pre-flight request headers, and so I'm seeing a 302. This works perfectly in Chrome, as cookies are in the pre-flight request headers and the subsequent POST goes through.

Why wouldn't this work in FF? What am I missing?

```
// assume url, boundEventHandler and uploadData are defined, as this definitely works in Chrome
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
xhr.addEventListener ("readystatechange", boundEventHandler, false); 
xhr.withCredentials = true;  // FWIW, I've also tried the string 'true'
xhr.send(uploadData);
```

Any ideas?  I see some posts that say I can proxy the request on the server side, but I'd prefer to get this working in accordance w/ the CORS spec.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of FF are you on, latest?

Answer (score 20):

Per spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests the preflight request never includes cookies.  Specifically, the spec says:

> - Exclude user credentials.

and that links to https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-credentials which says:

> The term user credentials for the purposes of this specification means
>   cookies, HTTP authentication, and client-side SSL (...).

That said, the code snippet you quote above shouldn't involve a preflight at all: there are no upload event listeners, the method is as simple method, and there are no author headers set.  So if you're really seeing a preflight request, the first question is why that's happening.  Do you have any extensions in Firefox that might be munging your XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: Good point... I had omitted the upload event listeners in the code snippet.   That's unfortunate that the spec doesn't allow for this.  It would seem that if someone wants to include cookies, they should be allowed.

Comment: The whole point of the preflight request is to protect the server from the web page by letting it know that someone wants to do some sort of weird request and allowing the server to explicitly white-list such things if it knows how to handle them properly... because many server by default do not know how to handle them properly.  That means no cookies, because that would open up an attack vector against unsuspecting servers.  The only way to allow cookies there would be if the _server_ indicated cookies are allowed.  But how would it do that?  The response to the preflight is how it does it.

Comment: Interesting.  I just tested, and Chrome doesn't do a preflight for the upload event listeners at all.  That seems... broken

Comment: And looks like the Chrome behavior is indeed a security bug in WebKit, fixed a few days ago.  See http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/113589

Comment: This was really helpful! I was enforcing authentication for my options method in app engine which caused this same error 302 returned by the server.  Removing authentication on the options method allowed my XHRs to respond properly now.

Answer (score 3):

Now Chromium(the 4th of July 2014) doesn't sent cookie with a preflight request. 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377541