# Custom Headers in jQuery Ajax OPTIONS call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, rest

So I know that if I have custom headers in my Ajax calls browser does a preflight to ensure that the resource is available. My problem is that my REST service uses Http-Authorization for security, but in the OPTIONS call this header is not getting passed in, even though it's added through beforeSend().

Do I have to reply to OPTIONS unauthenticated?

Comment: Code? What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: This is more of a conceptual question, code wont shed any light on it. I get '403 UnAuthorized' on the OPTIONS call since it doesn't have the Http-Authorization header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `OPTIONS` request is a preflight check for CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). I don't think you have control over the `OPTIONS` request, your browser will make it automatically.

Also, I don't necessarily believe this is a problem. You can implement the CORS reply headers on a whitelist basis. Like, say domains X and Y are allowed, but not Z. If you ask for `OPTIONS` comming from X you can reply 'allowed: X'. Similarly for Y. But if you come from Z you will say 'not allowed'.

A way around this, and for backwards compatibility with older browsers (`DomainRequest` anyone?) you can use JSONp, it's not as nice but way simpler.

Comment: I guess you're right, since it's a CORS I have full control over where the requests are coming from with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, so even if I let OPTIONS call go unauthenticated it shouldn't be that huge of a deal. But still would be nice to find out if it is possible or not at all

Comment: I think this question is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133497/cors-withcredentials-xhr-preflight-not-posting-cookies-in-firefox

Comment: The answer links to the CORS spec (**draft!**): http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#preflight-request which says you **can't** add user authentication or cookies or a body of any kind to the preflight request.